ARM-LINUX-GCC with LIBMODBUS


Hi everyone, I'm trying to compile a program using "arm-linux-gcc" with "libmodbus";
however it seems the compiler is not set up for libmodbus.
What should I do to fix it?

Are you cross-compiling or native compiling? It appears that libmodbus is trying to use gcc, so if the compilation environment doesn't match your expectations you'll have to check the configuration options (you may also have to adjust other settings if you're cross-compiling to point to the correct support libraries and output paths for example)

thanks for your help.
i checked the configuration options, and set compiler by command ./configure --host=arm-linux
I have created an executable file.
